# Преимущество класса Array перед ArrayList

Tags: c#, массивы

Обычно в программировании (в нубском) удобнее использовать ArrayList, т.к. он динамически расширяется и уменьшается. Меньше геморроя.

Возник такой вопрос: а есть ли у ArrayList минусы перед обычным Array? Когда лучше использовать Array, вместо листа?

Comment: Начиная с .NET 2.0 List<T> пришёл на замену ArrayList. Он строго типизированный и работает быстрее, особенно с простыми типами.

Comment: @Tolyandre Интересно, как `List<T>` может работать **быстрее** с небоксящимися типами, когда реализации `List<T>` и `ArrayList` используют `'private Object[] _items'` и `'private T[] _items'` соответственно.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, при работе с ArrayList вам потребуется приведение типов. Для ссылочных типов это очень быстрая проверка, но она есть.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во-первых, `ArrayList` не является строго типизированным. Т.е., все его методы принимают и возвращают элементы массива как `object`, и Вы теряете один из уровней защиты от ошибок. Во-вторых, `Array` - это низкоуровневый объект, который работает быстрее, а `ArrayList` - обёртка над ним, которая менее эффективна. Добавляя объект в конец списка, Вы должны понимать, что это не бесплатно: внутри него при этом пересоздаётся экземпляр `Array`, чтобы увеличить объём хранимых данных. Ну и ещё, массивы `Array` могут быть многомерными.